# Use dropdown value for a href link

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use a dropdown value for a href link with no success.

```js
function GetSelectedValue(){
    var e = document.getElementById("EquipeLabel");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

}
```

```html
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/4.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
          background-color: #ffcccc; 
          width:500px;
          margin:0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <br/>
    <table border="0">
        
        <tr> 
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="D_username">Equipe :</span>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" name="Equipe" id="EquipeLabel" onchange="GetSelectedValue()">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Team1">Team1</option>
                <option value="Team2">Team2</option>
                <option value="Team3">Team3</option>
                <option value="Team4">Team4</option>
            </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="Action.php"onclick="location.href=this.href+'?Equipe='+result;return false;"> Find </a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

the link url generate is something like this

> ....Action.php?Equipe=[object%20HTMLParagraphElement]

and I need this

> ...Action.php?Equipe=Team2

Comment: Why do you hack this inside a link?
If you just use a form element, and a submit button your logic will be applied automatically.

Comment: Also, you can't assign `innerHTML` to an element that doesn't exist. There is not an element in your HTML with the `id="result"`.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the selected option to a DOM element with id *result*, which doesn't exist. The `GetSelectedTeam` function should return the selected team or open the link directly (renaming the function to `OpenSelectedTeam` to reflect what is actually does), as displayed in the code below.

```
function OpenSelectedTeam() {
    var e = document.getElementById("EquipeLabel");
    var selectedTeam = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = window.location.href +'?Equipe=' + selectedTeam;
}
```

The related HTML hyperlink should be like this:

```
<a onclick="OpenSelectedTeam()"> Find </a>
```

The `onclick` event on the select list should be omitted, depending on what you want, navigate immediately after changing the selected team, or only when clicking the link.

Using a regular form might be a more appropiate solution however.

Comment: Thanks to you all, I will go with form like you suggest